# How to detect state change within JS for loop?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to build a countdown timer, which works like this:

```
const startCountdown = async () => {

   var countdownTime = 10;
   setDisplayTime(countdownTime);

   for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       
      await sleep(1000);
      countdownTime = countdownTime - 1;
      setDisplayTime(countdownTime);

   }
}
```

As you can see, this counts down from 10 (which will be a user input later on).

The sleep function looks like this:

```
const sleep = (ms) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};
```

The issue is that I want the user to be able to stop the timer. I initially thought that it would work like this:

```
const startCountdown = async () => {

   var countdownTime = 10;
   setDisplayTime(countdownTime);

   for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

      if (timerStopped) {
         
         break;
      
      } else {
       
         await sleep(1000);
         countdownTime = countdownTime - 1;
         setDisplayTime(countdownTime);

   }
}
```

But it doesn't look like the new state is passed into the for loop, it just remembers what the state was when the function started.

Is there a way to work around this? I don't need the timer to be paused and restarted, I just need it to stop (and then I can reset it from there).

Answer (score 1):

I built a rxjs version for you... I find this solution somewhat easier, because of the ability to manipulate streams.

```js
const {
  BehaviorSubject,
  timer
} = rxjs

const {
  filter,
  tap,
  withLatestFrom
} = rxjs.operators;

const
  startButton = document.getElementById("startButton"),
  pauseButton = document.getElementById("pauseButton"),
  continueButton = document.getElementById("continueButton"),
  stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton");

class Timer {

  _time = 0;

  _timerSubscription;

  _paused = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  setTime(time) {
    this._time = time
  }

  start() {
    const step = 1000;
    this._timerSubscription = timer(0, step).pipe(withLatestFrom(this._paused), filter(([v, paused]) => !paused)).subscribe(val => {
      if (this._time <= 0) {
        this.stop();
      }
      console.log(this._time);
      this._time -= step;
    });
  }

  pause() {
    this._paused.next(true)
  }

  continue () {
    this._paused.next(false)
  }

  stop() {
    this.reset();
    if (this._timerSubscription) {
      this._timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  reset() {
    this._time = 0;
  }
}

const myTimer = new Timer();

myTimer.setTime(10000);

startButton.onclick = () => {
  myTimer.start();
};

pauseButton.onclick = () => {
  myTimer.pause();
}

stopButton.onclick = () => {
  myTimer.stop();
}

continueButton.onclick = () => {
  myTimer.continue();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>


<button id="startButton">Start</button>
<button id="stopButton">Stop</button>
<button id="pauseButton">Pause</button>
<button id="continueButton">Continue</button>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Will this work on React Native? Will need to check it out.

Comment: It should... I've seen people using react native and rxjs together :)

Comment: Unfortunately not.

I'm still working on it, but this code:

     pause() {
        this._paused.next(true)
      }

Did not change the variable in the withLatestFrom() function. It just stayed false no matter what.